# Assistance Coding a Message Box Based on Text Box Input

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm building an app using Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2015 in which a user enters numbers or letters into a text box; however, when letters are entered into the text box and a button is pressed, I need a message box to pop up and say, "Please Enter a five-digit number." I know I can use the KeyPress to command to make it so it will only accept numbers but in this case, I need the message box to come up when the button is pressed. I'm not sure how to code the application to accept number input while responding to letter input with a message box when the button is pressed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I am sorry, after second reading I think I understand better.

After any keypress, split the string value of your input field into array.

Loop through the array and every time check if the value is numeric. In visual basic it was possible with IsNumeric(), but C# doesn't have it I think. In that case use this as your ISNumeric function:

```
public bool IsNumeric(string value)
{
    return value.All(char.IsNumber);
}
```

EDIT2: in your case you will not even need a loop. Just check the whole input against through IsNumeric() function. However, check it out if it works with a leading 0 too. If not, use a loop as I suggested.

Comment: Though the length of the value won't help me with distinguishing between letters and numbers, will it?

Comment: Or you can do it even without the loop I believe :)